# $\LaTeX$ turning into $\\LaTeX$ in the meta titles on the main site

Tags: bug, status-completed, tex

What's this about?  The question on the main site (that links to [Test the new LaTeX markdown in this Sandbox question!](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question)) gives an error $\LaTeX$ ("Misplaced \"), but when meta links it, it works fine.

The error'ing TeX has a source of `\\LaTeX`, but the functional ones are just `\LaTeX`.

[image]

Comment: Hey, you were looking at my question! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a small decoding issue when consuming data from the API (yes, we use the public API internally for things like this). It is fixed, but we cache that data for about an hour. It should work after that.

Comment: I saw this as well, and brought the issue to Meta, where I found a related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63479/146495  Does the decoding issue fix that as well?

Comment: @reemrevnivek it fixes a *decoding* issue, but it won't make "English" (for example) spin up the necessay tex clientside scripts... In short: not afaik

Comment: FYI @MarcGravell I've not been to this site in many days, and I've not logged in on this computer I don't think, and I just got this bug. Find me in chat if you like.

Comment: @drach still bugging out for me as well.

Comment: @Earlz @drachenstern I've just checked - are you sure you aren't talking about the link to **this question**? Where we *expect* it to be malformed because the title is reporting malformed latex?

Comment: @Marc well, I am talking about this question. I think it's ugly/tacky for it to show such an error in a title.

Comment: @earlz maybe, but at least that is the *expected* behaviour, consistent with the entire site; the previous behaviour was incorrect, unexpected, and inconsistent.

Comment: @Marc No I'm talking about the bug in particular, not for this question. I thought the bug was less specific than a given question.

Comment: @drach - yes, but the only question I can now reproduce this on is ***this one***, where it is *correct* to misbehave because it has illegal latex in the title. Can you cite a question (other than this one) where you see this?

Comment: @Marc ~ You'll have to wait till I get home tonight and get on my laptop (history, original reproduction of error). I'll post a new question tomorrow and then @you with a link in the teacher's lounge, sound good?

Comment: Aye, all fine here

Comment: @MarcGravell well crap, I can't find any questions that are doing it :\ ... and I can't find the one in particular that I was looking at last night ... I'm certain I was tabbing back and forth so I imagine it got lost in the tabhistory somewhere.